# When I make an e-mail intent in kotlin, the recipient mail is not added directly

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, email, android-intent, imagebutton

```
binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.requestWallpaper->{
                    val emailIntent=Intent().apply {
                        action=Intent.ACTION_SEND
                        data= Uri.parse("mailto:")
                        type="text/plain"
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"test@gmail.com")
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"request wallpaper")
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"request wallpaper")
                    }
                    if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(this!!.packageManager) !=null){
                        emailIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm")
                        startActivity(emailIntent)
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"No app available to send email!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
```

When the navigation drawer opens, the user will want to make a wallpaper request and when he presses the imagebutton, I want him to send an e-mail to test@gmail.com via gmail for now, but test@gmail.com is not added directly to the "to" part of gmail.When I run it on the emulator, the email subject and e-mail text are added, but the recipient e-mail is not added, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *so* close here, the only thing that's missing is the `Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` extra. That property is expecting an array of `String` values rather than a single `String`.

```kotlin
binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.requestWallpaper -> {
            val emailIntent = Intent().apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
                type = "text/plain"
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("test@gmail.com"))
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "request wallpaper")
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "request wallpaper")
            }
            if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(this.packageManager) != null) {
                emailIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm")
                startActivity(emailIntent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "No app available to send email!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know that you need the `type="text/plain"` property either, but it shouldn't hurt anything. Also, if you skip the `setPackage` step it'll allow the OS to ask which email app to use.

Comment: wow I'm really close. I wrote your code and it really worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you. Actually I don't know exactly what the text/plain property is. It was always added in the codes I researched, so I added it.